# iptables block port from local network

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I have a problem inside my infrastructure.
chat.example.com port 8185 is reachable outside my infrastructure with a port fowarding to the right box.
But inside my infrastructure, i'm not able to reach it.

```
root@node1:/etc/iptables# telnet chat.example.com 8185
Trying 91.x.x.x...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

and outside my infrastructure :

```
guilhem@guilhem-Lenovo-B50-30:~$ telnet chat.example.com 8185
Trying 91.x.x.x...
Connected to chat.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I don't understand why i can't reach it from my infra...

Here is my iptables rules :

```
root@node1:/etc/iptables# cat rules.v4
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Nov 26 13:51:03 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1577:148565]
:INPUT ACCEPT [484:29040]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [403:31487]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [47:2820]
-A PREROUTING -d 91.x.x.x/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8185 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.100.30:8185
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov 26 13:51:03 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Nov 26 13:51:03 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [4:407]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8185 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.0.100.30/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8185 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov 26 13:51:03 2015
```

If you have any idea... Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a DNS issue. You most likely setup your external DNS to point to your firewall/router (external IP). Your firewall then does an IP/Port forward to the correct IP on your network.

For this to work on your **internal** network, you will need to do a similar DNS setup. But you need to point the address to your internal IP address.

You can do it for your whole network via a DNS server you setup. 
Or if you only need this done for one computer then you can just make an entry into the HOST file of the computer:

> sudo nano /etc/hosts

Then type: (according to this format **IP HOSTNAME.DOMAIN ALIAS**)

> LIP.###.###.### chat.example.com example

LIP = the local ip address of the server you are trying to access

Then try to ping 'chat.example.com' and see if it points to the right IP.

> ping chat.example.com

Be mindful that if you use the host file that this will only work on that computer. Any other computer on the network will have to have a similar entry on their host file. If you have many computers trying to access that, then it would be worth considering setting up a DNS server.